# Custom Validation on Infopath Fields? C#

Tags: infopath, validation

How can I apply custom validation to Infopath 2010 fields which stretches beyond the basic Rules and Templates?

I am looking to validate a custom field which needs to be validated much like a Credit Card Number. The field itself needs to be a template of **###-###-###** but needs to be validated with the Luhn Algorithm like Credit Card Numbers are. I can do this with C# but am unsure of how to apply C# Validation to an Infopath field.

Is this possible, and if so how can I go about doing this?

Comment: You should edit to improve your question instead of [duplicating it](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47230/validate-social-insurance-number-in-infopath-with-luhn-algorithm)  Also, I cannot believe that you do not know how to use search on internet

Comment: I come to stack instead of just searching the internet because I normally receive well thought-out criticism and opinions. Not because I forgot how to use Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do it in code behind in the InfoPath form.

Here is a link to that. You can still use you C# code to do it. Take a look below.

http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/infopath-basics-3-ways-validate-data-infopath.htm

Comment: Depends on the complexity of the validation. If you can use regular expression, etc. then go with that option. From my experience, I recommend that you avoid using the InfoPath code-behind as much as possible or try not write too much logic in the code behind. Maintaining the code behind is a headache and makes your IP solution more complex and flimsy (there are some compatiblity issues as well, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772074.aspx). You can also write a service to do the validation for you. You can then consume this service in your IP form.

Comment: I recommend Reg Expressions also but he is trying to run an algorithm I think C# is the only way. If the algorithm is compute intensive I would query a service for the validation and let the service handle the work.

Comment: Joseph - I believe that tutorial is only for Infopath 2007 and not 2010. Lots of those steps do not seem to line up with 2010, unless I'm wrong?

Comment: This link is related to InfoPath 2010 and should guide you in the correct direction. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2010/03/18/introduction-to-programming-in-infopath-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you can create algorithms of any complexity through Rules (including iterations using hidden fields) without code behind.

Also note that some compatibity/type of Infopath form templates like Sharepoint List Form types do not permit (client-side) code behind.

The Sharepoint List Form type with locked Main data connection /source is generated for you when/if one presses:

- Customize Form button on ribbon having navigated to a sharepoint list in a browser
- Sharepoint List button in File > New of Infopath Form Designer 2010

It does not mean that one cannot work with sharepoint lists in other types of IP form templates.